# How to remove top margin above bigcup

Tags: spacing

I want to remove the margin above `\bigcup` symbol :

[image]

```
\begin{displaymath}
\prod_{i\in I} X_i \bydef \left\{\left. x\in\left( \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i \right)^I \right\vert  \: \forall i\in I, x(i)\in X_i \right\}
\end{displaymath}
```

I don't know how to proceed ? Thank for help :)

Comment: there is no margin, it is just that the () are vertically centred on the math axis. use \bigl(  not \left(,

Comment: It doesn't change anything :(

Comment: welcome to TeX.SE! please, provide code for your equation, the best as small, complete document.

Comment: @Phoenix yes it would, see the posted answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't autosize *any* of the "fence" symbols. Instead, I'd use `\Big` and `\bigg` sizing directives. Observe that TeX automatically (and correctly) inserts some whitespace around `\biggm\vert`; this doesn't happen if one writes `\middle\vert` (or `\right\vert`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\prod_{i\in I} X_i = \biggl\{ x\in\Bigl(\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i \Bigr)^{\!I} 
    \biggm\vert  \forall i\in I, x(i)\in X_i \biggr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

is this better?

[image]

considering David Carlisle comment you can rewrite your equation into:

```
\[
\prod_{i\in I} X_i = \left\{ x\in\biggl(\ \bigcup_{i\in I} X_i \biggr)^I \middle\vert  \: \forall i\in I, x(i)\in X_i \right\}
\]
```

Comment: There is some margin as \bigcup_{i\in I}^{ "something" } :/

Comment: ups, I don't know :-(. I overlooked this nonses in OP code. corrected.